# AR and MA models give the same Residual ACF and have the same coefficients

Tags: arima

I tried to estimate parameters for the AR(1) and MA(1) models. I got 0.342 for theta and -0.343 for phi (coefficients of AR(1) and MA(1) respectively). The residual ACF for both the models was also the same.

My question is if this is possible? Or that I have an issue with my Matlab code?

Answer (score 0):

This is quite possible and is to be expected as all AR models can be expressed as  MA models . If the ar(1) coefficient is .33333 as is your case it's negated inverse is -1/3 or -.33333. For example an AR(1) model with coefficient .5 generates {1+.5B**1 + .25*B**2 + .125*B**3 + .0625*B**4 ,,,,,}

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Also, I am getting different values for the RMSE. Is this possible?

Comment: i would not expect that

Answer (score 0):

So the RMSE must be the same?  I think the two RMSE values are very close.

Also,  what is the reason for the residual acf being the same?